# Spark SQL: Subtract values of columns and get absolute value

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

In Spark SQL, I need to subtract values of two columns and check if the absolute value of the result is greater than certain value. How can I do that? I tried this:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
f.abs((f.col("col1") - f.col("col2"))) > 100
```

But this is throwing PySpark exception. I believe it's because the 'abs' function takes in a 'Column' NOT a value. Is that correct?

How can I do what I want to do in Spark SQL?

Comment: Your logic seems OK, please add a reproducible example of your issue. Also please add the full exception message.

Comment: Why was it down voted? If you vote down, at least add a comment so the person asking would know the reason & would ask a better question next time.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use the `expr` function of SQL, if the absolute value is greater than 100, it returns 1, otherwise it returns 0.

```
df = df.withColumn('flag', F.expr('if(abs(col1 - col2) > 100, 1, 0)'))
```